# Getting the year of the month

Tags: date

If you use `date.today().month()+4` how will you get its year. For instance, today's month is September and you add 4 in the month in the given statement above. We know that the year of the today's month that was added by 4 is 2015 because it will be January, how to get the exact year based on the month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the exact year:
Date.Today().addmonths(number).year();

Examples:

- Date.Today().addmonths(3).year() will result in 2014
- Date.Today().addmonths(4).year() will result in 2015
- Date.Today().addmonths(16).year() will result in 2016

Comment: I think this much more simpler. :)

Comment: `Date.Today().month()+1` would this be a wrong approach? what are the possible future error to this approach? Let's say the date today is December its value is 12, therefore when we add 1 it will become 13. However when we use `Utility.GetMonth(date.today().month()+1)` it will return January.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `Date.Today().month()+1` instead of `Date.Today().addMonths(1).month()`? As you said, the first statement will return 13 when it is December while `Date.Today().addMonths(1).month()` will return 1. It is safer to use `Date.Today().addMonths(1).month()`.

Comment: well as beginner in salesforce development, I still don't know some of the syntax, and what are the good practices. I'm in the process of developing while learning. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use a date variable in your code, then use the addMonths() method.

```
Date myDate = system.today();

myDate = myDate.addMonths(4);

system.debug(myDate);
system.debug(myDate.year());
```

The second debug statement correctly returns 2015 (as we are now into September).

Comment: appreciated the effort to answer my question :)